# Redirect stdout of one Popen to another Popen stdin

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I am trying to send the output of one process as an input to another process using the following code block:

```
p1 = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(dgxmcmd, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout= PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

But the p2 is getting an exception as no such file or directory. It seems the p1 stdout terminates.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/toolbox", line 160, in <module>
d.brokerProfile()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/toollib/deploy.py", line 340, in 
brokerProfile
self.dgxm(cmd1)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/toollib/deploy.py", line 327, in dgxm
p2 = Popen([dgxmcmd], stdin = p1.stdout, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Anyway to figure out what is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Additional Information: dgxm is a third party tool which accepts commands. Commands are dynamically generated from p1 and then sent to p2 for execution using the third party tool.

Comment: Please show what ``command`` and ``dgxmcmd`` are

Comment: @APorter1031 I have added that information.  I will try to create a standalone test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead just do this

```
import os
p1 = os.popen(command)
p1=p1.read()
p2 = Popen(dgxmcmd, stdin=p1, stdout= PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

that should work if there is no further information

Comment: anything inside os.popen(" ") will execute as it would in command terminal, so I will need to have more information but no reason to believe that it won't work

Comment: It didn't work as the command was a list. I ended up using one Popen rather than using PIPE between the two Popen.